# Como executar áudio com PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4, pyqt-5

Existe alguma maneira de executar um arquivo de áudio com PyQt?

É possível fazer isso apenas com PyQt ou precisa de instalar outra biblioteca?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se quiser usar o método nativo da PyQt, tem o `QSound`:

```
meusom = QSound("alerta.wav")
meusom.play()
```

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsound.html

Há um método que retorna um valor *bool*, para você saber se o recurso está disponível:

```
bool QSound::isAvailable()
```

Isto é útil para você verificar se precisa de um meio alternativo de notificação, caso a plataforma não consiga reproduzir o áudio.

A pergunta fala em PyQt 4, mas para quem estiver usando a 5, compensa uma olhada na `QSoundEffect` também, mais versátil e de baixa latência:

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente, `QMedia` está disponível apenas no [PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qmediaplayer.html) (já que `QMedia` requer Qt5), mas o próprio Python pode fazer algumas coisas sem precisar do PyQt.

Existe a lib [*playsound*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1), que não tem dependências, pode-se instalar via `pip`:

```
$ pip install playsound
```

E chama-la assim:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('/home/pasta/play.mp3')
```