# Erro e musica escrita em Python

Tags: python-3.x

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Queria executar uma musica em python mas quando arrasto ela para o meu projeto ela fica "escrita", como posso fazer para executa-la?(sou novo em python)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Como executar áudio com PyQt?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164923)... [player MP3 com Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203600)

Comment: O IDE não é o projeto, o IDE é só o editor mesmo, você tem que colocar a musica na "pasta" do projeto, então tente usar uma das respostas em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164923/3635

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

Podes ouvir a música com a ajuda da biblioteca pygame bem como existe outras soluções. A sua música deve estar no mesmo diretório que o arquivo

import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('minhaMusica.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()

Comment: Boa noite,
ja utilizei essa biblioteca só que o pycharm nunca toca a musica, tentei usar essa biblioteca com esses mesmos comando diversas vezes e ele da um erro diferente fora q minha musica fica em 'scratch file' sempre que coloco no diretorio do projeto como mostrado na imagem acima

Comment: Tens o pygame instalado ?

Comment: Sim, definitivamente sim

Comment: pip install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in

Comment: ele toca musicas de diversos tamanhos certo?Ou ele é limitado quanto ao tempo?

Comment: Podes mostrar o seu código? Definidamente algo está errado no meu funcionou. Qual Sistemas operacional usas?

Comment: Acho q tem algo haver com a minha musica estar em Stratch file , isso é comum?Porque antes de eu fazer alguma cagada, ela não ficava em stratch file,mas olhe o código:
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('purple.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()

Comment: Faz um print por favor. Na tua pasta apenas deves ter o ficheiro do script e a música, a música e o ficheiro do script não  podem estar numa subpasta

Comment: coloquei outro print la em cima

Comment: A tua música tem 4,74 MB é de 2,56 MB. Procura cortar a música ou reduzir o tamanho

Comment: ok muito obrigado

Comment: Quando resolver da a pergunta como resolvido por favor